# Janusgraph not utilizing CPU

Tags: janusgraph

I am using Janusgraph 0.6.3 with Cassandra as the primary backend (composite index) and elastic search as the secondary backend (mixed index).

I have Janus and Cassandra installed on a machine with below specs

CPU: 32 core

RAM: 128 GB

SSD: 500 GB

I am running the below gremlin query on this graph,

```
g.V().hasLabel("seeker").has("p_uuid", seeker_p_uuid).outE("worked").as_("e1").inV().inE("worked").as_("e2")\
                .outV().as_("b").outE("worked").where(inV().hasLabel("company").has("company_name", recruiter_name)).has("current", 1)\
                .where("e1", lt("e2")).by("start_date").by("end_date").where("e1", gt("e2")).by("end_date").by("start_date")\
                .select("e1", "e2", "b").range_(0,10).toList()
```

and for some cases, this query returns `Graph Timeout Error`.

I have monitoring the Janus and Cassandra machine and it's CPU and RAM are not being completely utilized. They are at 20-30% CPU utilization and 15-20% RAM Utilization.

My question is, if the CPU is left unutilised, then why does the query give `Timeout Exception`. Shouldn't the CPU must have been used about 60-70% atleast ?

I am using both `Composite` and `Mixed index` to make the query more faster.

Comment: On a 32 core machine it is unlikely that a single Gremlin query would take up all available CPU as Gremlin queries tend to have a single threaded execution model.  How much data is that query having to touch when it times out? Are you connecting directly to Cassandra via JanusGraph embedded in the application or are you using a Gremlin Server in the mix as well?